# BizTalk Server Admin Console slow if some servers in the group are stopped

Tags: biztalk

As part of our scaling and disaster recovery design, we have virtual machines in our BizTalk Server group that are "Stopped (deallocated)" in Azure so that we are not paying for them when they are not needed.

However, we are finding that the BizTalk Admin Console is running very slowly when refreshing the group page or the host instances page when there are host instances on servers it cannot find.

Ideally, we would prefer to not to remove these VMs from the group so that: we can deploy code to them, quickly scale out-in, and failover to the secondary region within our RTO.

- Is there anything we can do about this?
- What are others doing to achieve the objectives above?

Comment: In your DR strategy, are you assuming BizTalk SQL are going to be available in other region?

Comment: @VikasBhardwaj - we are using standard BizTalk log shipping design for the sql databases. But even with this approach, the BizTalk app servers in secondary region need to be in the same group.

Comment: I think You are bound to have some latency with admin console when DR VMs are not online. We use a completely different approach for DR and don’t use log shipping. our DBs are replicated via disk replication and VMs too. So its like having a different group at another region which switch on in DR situation and keeps same IP for servers.

Comment: Whist I sure it works fine, I assume you have accepted that this is not a supported design by Microsoft (https://blogs.biztalk360.com/biztalk-backup-disaster-recovery-log-shipping-is-the-only-official-option-why/).  I assume you have accepted some element of data loss beyond standard 15 minute RPO with standard log shipping configuration.
Any other ideas out there on how to stop the Admin Console working slowly in a standard Microsoft DR topology with VMs deallocated in the secondary region?

Comment: Looks like there was a fix for this issue in BizTalk Server 2013 Cumulative Update 3 "2701417 : FIX: Slow performance when you manage host instances in a server group that contains offline servers by using the BizTalk Server Administration console" https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3088676.